# PHP math with random numbers with random mathematical symbols

Tags: php

I want to ask how can I perform mathematics calculations with 2 random numbers ($a, $b). Im using $c as random number to clarify which mathematical symbol to use.

```
$a = mt_rand(1,1000);
$b = mt_rand(1,1000);
$c = mt_rand(1,1000);
if ($c < 100) {
    $math = "/";
} else if ($c > 900) {
    $math = "*";
} else if (500 < $c && $c < 900) {
    $math = "-";
} else {
    $math = "+";
}

$calculate = "$a $math $b";
echo $calculate; // provide mathematical task to user
echo "<br />";
$result = $a "$math" $b; // trying to calculate result
echo $result;
```

My question is how hould I use "$math" variable to clarify mathematical symbol? Thanks for the help.

Example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$math = "*";
```

Result is "1 * 2"

Comment: Have you tried excluding the double quotes around $math in the second to last statement and concatenating, e.g. $result = $a.$math.$b;

Comment: @Craig Yes, it returns as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the result, you can use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) by changing these lines:

```
$result = $a "$math" $b; // trying to calculate result
echo $result;
```

to:

```
$calculatePHP = '$result = ('.$a.$math.$b.');';
eval($calculatePHP);
echo $result;
```